# How to add new display resolution in Wayland?

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, wayland

I have Nvidia graphics in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My monitor native resolution is 2560x1440 and is connected by HDMI interface. The system cannot find monitor resolution automatically. The right resolution is not in list if I try to set it.

I can set new one using X11 and xrandr by easy way. But if I switch to Wayland, all is bad.

The graphics has a low performance and low resolution too and I do no know how to add new resolution according to my monitor. The problem is similar with other Nvidia cards and monitors I have tried. Does exist any feasible way for adding of "non-listed" resolution in Wayland?

Answer (score 0):

try to read currently used edid from X11 working env,
and force to use it in Wayland by adding cmdline drm parameters to /etc/default/grub
it's the answer I got

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have run into this same brick wall and Wayland. Why is Ubuntu using it as a default window server when it clearly has some rather large limitations . I can't run a monitor at it's designed resolution and I am prevented from adding it by wayland.. anyone else see a design flaw here